# javascript list of english words for a game

Tags: javascript, dictionary, spell-checking

I'm making a simple JS game that needs a list of English dictionary words. Will I need to build the list myself, or is it possible to access the system's or browser's spell-check dictionary - or maybe there's another solution?

Comment: Have you checked out this? http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html You could at least get the words from that list which would remove the task of handwriting every single word.

Comment: Use the list from a friendly neighborhood Linux installation. `/usr/share/dict/words` has almost 100,000 words in it.

Comment: That English Open Word List looks great! But somewhat dated...looks like it hasn't been updated in 15 years (not a HUGE deal, but yes, lots of words get added each year)

Comment: You can take a look at Aspell as well. It has english dictionary (ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html). To dump world list from the dictionary checkout http://superuser.com/questions/137957/how-to-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-simple-list-of-words.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Aspell](http://aspell.net/) English dictionary.
Aspell English dictionary is availabe at: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html.

To dump world list from the Aspell dictionary checkout:

- https://superuser.com/questions/137957/how-to-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-simple-list-of-words
- http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10619/dump-an-aspell-dictionary-as-a-word-list
- http://aspell.net/man-html/Dumping-the-Contents-of-the-Word-List.html

The command to dump English list of words should look something like:

```
aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > words.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest solution that I found is getting a text or JSON file from anywhere(on web) which contains all the English words(not meanings like in dictionary). I got it from [this repository](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/), this contains a text file and a JSON file.

You can easily read data from JSON file using javascript or other programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

with node you can install [random-words](https://github.com/punkave/random-words)

```
npm install random-words
```

import it and you're done:

```
var randomWords = require('random-words');
console.log(randomWords());
```

[requirebin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=a42d7f856bcb68185d8db311317361fc)

Comment: Worth noting that Random Words includes a very small subset of the English language

Answer (score 3):

The wordlist for Firefox spellchecking seems to come from this repository: https://github.com/marcoagpinto/aoo-mozilla-en-dict. So you could download it there to get a word list.

You can also install the dictionary as addon (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/language-tools/) but I don't know if or how the dictionary-addons can be accessed with JavaScript directly from inside the browser.

Comment: Careful, there are some naughty and rather offensive words in here. Depending on their use, they may not be words you want appearing in your product.

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for a simple JSON endpoint I could use for a workbook - wound up uploading one to github:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jesseditson/1e6b2b524814320515ccfe7e2f856eda/raw/17d61fa1e80e14b13c4525b09f84148772586b59/words.json

Answer (score 1):

you can to  use this:

https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JavaScript_SpellChecking_Dictionaries

there are many languages:

```
 Afrikaans (South Africa)
 American English (USA)
 Australian English
 Brazil (Modern Brazilian Portuguese)
 British English (UK)
 Catalan (Catalonia)
 Canadian English
 Danish Dictionary (Dansk)
 Dutch & Flemish (Nederlands)
 Gaelic
 German Dictionary (Deutsch)
 French (Francais)
 Frisian (Frysk, Seeltersk & Mooring)
 International English
 Italian (Italiano)
 Malaysian (Bahasa Malaysia)
 Portuguese (Portugues - Brazil and Portugal)
 Spanish (Espanol - Americas & Spain)
 Swedish (Svenska)
 Welsh (Cymric)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Linked by @aryaman , I too used that GitHub page when I needed an Array for Auto-correct TextBox. https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.txt[][1]

But If you are looking for a Javascript Array Soultion, Just Create a Python File in the Same directory as The words.txt file and type this into Python File

```
filepath = 'words.txt'
print("var anyname = [")
with open(filepath) as fp:
   for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
       print("'{}',".format(line))
print("]")
```

Just Copy Paste the Output to your Code File and Done !

*! Note - It's really big file, I recommend you to use this one from the same respoitory  https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt[][1] . It contains words without any Numbers. Also, Python Script could take 2-3 hours, mine is currently running that's why I'm writing this. I will soon Edit The Answer with Direct Link to File if it is done !*

Answer (score 1):

I recently found the following npm repo which contains a list of English words from [here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/).

https://github.com/danakt/spell-checker.js

`npm i spell-checker-js`

```
const spell = require('spell-checker-js')

// Load dictionary
spell.load('en')

// Checking text
const check = spell.check('Some text to check, blahblahblah, olololo')

console.log(check)
// -> ['blahblahblah', 'olololo']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get a worlist here http://marcoagpinto.cidadevirtual.pt/proofingtoolgui.html .. look for the WORDLIST link on the right

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let theWord = 'green'

const validateWord = async() => {
  let failed = false;
  //Check if it is a valid english word
  await fetch(
    `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${theWord}`
  ).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == "404") {
      alert("Please Enter Valid Word");
      failed = true;
    }
  });
  return !failed;
}
```