# Trigger a function in Javascript, if the word is in dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I want to perform an action after the user typed in a textbox. I will be using `onkeyup` in the textbox.

i want a condition, that will allow the user to perform a task, only if the typed word is a dictionary word or a proper word.

Eg :

- if the user types `hello`, then alert the word Hello.
- if the user types  `helr`, then alert that this is not a dictionary word.

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="chk();"/>
<span id="indicate"></span>
```

**Javascript :**

```
function chk() {
  if(spellcheck()) {
     document.getElementById("indicate").innerHTML = "Correct Word";
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("indicate").innerHTML = "Wrong Word";
  }
}
```

**Please Help me defining the `function spellcheck()` which will return 1 or 0.**

I want this to be performed in client side itself, **using javascript**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem? Have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I don't know how to make a spellcheck in javascript and return a true or false. That is really what i need

Comment: I have edited the question. Check it

Answer (score 1):

Returning 1 and 0 is not good for JavaScript. Better return true and false from the function. Now, you can define your dictionary in form of array and then check if the input word is present in dictionary or not.

```
var dictionary = ['Hello', 'Welcome', 'Bye'];

function spellcheck(value) {
  var returnVal = false;
  var length = dictionary.length;
  for (var inc = length - 1; inc >= 0; inc--) {
    if(value.toUpperCase() === dictionary[inc].toUpperCase()) {
      returnVal = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

You can see full example here http://jsbin.com/IgaPEBi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How am i supposed to add all the dictionary words in a array variable?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493594/javascript-list-of-english-words-for-a-game

Comment: Selected as accepted answer then rejected. May I know what went wrong?

Comment: I chose your answer as it worked good. I made loading all the dictionary words. but it made few issues like slowing down the app. So, i found that i should not load one. i have to access the dictionary words of the system

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Typo.js](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js) dictionary

To use Typo, simply include the typo.js file in your extension's background page, and then initialize the dictionary like so:

```
var dictionary = new Typo("en_US");
var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check("hello");
```

or http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/ for an auto suggestions box.

Comment: It is not working. I dont know what is the problem. http://jsbin.com/oDoTOSa/2/edit

Comment: You need to follow the Typo.js installation instructions https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js -see edit

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to an API dictionary service, there are some opensource ones:

[wiktionary](http://dictionary-api.org/)

[glosbe.com](http://glosbe.com/a-api)

[dictionary-api](http://dictionary-api.org/)

When the user finishes typing you can use a function to make an async call (AJAX with JS or Jquery) to the APIs endopoint; if the object in the response is not void or null or just states there are no words in the dictionary, your function can return 0, else 1.

Usually the endpoint address is something like URL/*action*/*word* , where *action* is what you want to know and *word* is the actual word you look for.